# Show subtotals in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is to SUM IF the value is 1 in every subtotal created . I've tried using Subtotal option but I can't make it work (maybe because I'm not good at using Excel) and sometime I get 0 and 1 in groups with the sum. So I decide to make a VBA.

This is almost the group of data

```
- |    A    |    B    |  C  |
-----------------------------
1 | Names   | Points  |  N  |
-----------------------------
2 | Grimer  |   1     |  88 |
3 | Grimer  |   1     |  88 |
4 | Grimer  |   0     |  88 |
5 | Psyduck |   1     |  54 |
6 | Psyduck |   0     |  54 |
7 | Psyduck |   0     |  54 |
8 | Pikachu |   1     |  25 | 
9 | Pikachu |   1     |  25 |
10| Pikachu |   1     |  25 |
```

And this is what I'm trying to get:

```
     |    A    |    B    |  C  |
-------------------------------
   1 | Names   | Points  |  N  |
-------------------------------
|  2 | Grimer  |   1     |  88 |
|  3 | Grimer  |   1     |  88 |
|  4 | Grimer  |   0     |  88 |
-  5 | Grimer  |   2     |  88 |
|  6 | Psyduck |   1     |  54 |
|  7 | Psyduck |   0     |  54 |
|  8 | Psyduck |   0     |  54 |
-  9 | Psyduck |   1     |  54 |
|  10| Pikachu |   1     |  25 | 
|  11| Pikachu |   1     |  25 |
|  12| Pikachu |   1     |  25 |
-  13| Pikachu  |   3     |  25 |
```

Those dashed at the beginning of every row (starting from 2) are the groups that I want  to create (and the B cell of every row is the result.. it should be bold). The following code is to get the previous result (the table). It works but I would like to know if there is a way if there is a better solution doing it on Excel without programming. Or... Is there any error because when I run it, it takes a few seconds (for more than 4000 rows).

```
Sub GetPointsByPokemon()

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        Dim Fila As Integer, InitRow As Integer, Suma As Integer

        PkNumber = .Range("C2").Value
        InitRow = 2
        ActualRow = 2
        Suma = 0

        Do Until .Cells(ActualRow, 1).Value = ""
            If .Cells(ActualRow, 2).Value = 1 Then
                Suma = Suma + 1
            End If

            If PkNumber <> .Range("C" & (ActualRow + 1)).Value Then
                .Cells(ActualRow, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                PkNumber = .Range("C" & (ActualRow + 2)).Value

                .Range(ActualRow & ":" & ActualRow).Offset(1).Value = .Range(ActualRow & ":" & ActualRow, 1).Value

                .Range("B" & (ActualRow + 1)).Value = Suma
                .Rows(InitRow & ":" & ActualRow).Group

                ActualRow = ActualRow + 1
                InitRow = ActualRow + 1
                Suma = 0
            End If

            ActualRow = ActualRow + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

All the data is an example and I had to change some values on the code. I have done it using MySQL but I really want to know how to do it on excel (and vba) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the subtotal need to be in the same column?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the same column. I'm gonna highlight those results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like **Bulbasaur.**

I also don't like this approach, because you are hardcoding subtotals onto your worksheet **and weaving them into your source data**.

But here is the code if you still want to do this. It is ugly but it works.

```
Sub AddSubtotals()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim numberOfRows As Long

  ' number of pokemon
  numberOfRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  ' do bottom row first
  Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 1).value = Cells(numberOfRows, 1).value
  Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R[-" & numberOfRows - 1 & "]C[-1]:R[-" & numberOfRows - (numberOfRows - 1) & "]C[-1],""" & Cells(numberOfRows, 1).value & """,R[-" & numberOfRows - 1 & "]C[0]:R[-" & numberOfRows - (numberOfRows - 1) & "]C[0])"
  ' convert to value
  Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 2).value = Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 2).value
  Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 3).value = Cells(numberOfRows, 3).value

  Range(Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 1), Cells(numberOfRows + 1, 3)).Font.Bold = True

  ' insert blank row in between each group of pokemon
  ' loop backwards because we are inserting rows
  For i = numberOfRows To 3 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).value Then
      Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

      ' copy pokemon name down
      Cells(i, 1).value = Cells(i - 1, 1).value

      ' put formula into Points field
      Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R[-" & i - 1 & "]C[-1]:R[-" & i - (i - 1) & "]C[-1],""" & Cells(i, 1).value & """,R[-" & i - 1 & "]C[0]:R[-" & i - (i - 1) & "]C[0])"
      ' convert to value
      Cells(i, 2).value = Cells(i, 2).value

      ' copy N value down
      Cells(i, 3).value = Cells(i - 1, 3).value

      Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Font.Bold = True

    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

### Sample data before code:

[image: before running code]

### Sample data after code:

[image: after running code]

Comment: I'm new doing this VBA. I will try this tonight (and learn everything you have coded)!

Comment: Yesterday I tried my code on Windows and it didn't worked as I expected. Haha. When I tested your code, excel crashed. I forgot that the data was on other columns and now is working. My work will be to understand your code and group them! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way without VBA:

1. Choose *Data | Subtotal* ... *At each change in*: `Names` *Use function*: `Sum`, *Check*: `Points` and `N`.
2. Select column C and choose to replace (Ctrl+H) the `9,` in the subtotal formula with another summary function such as: `1,` (average), `4,` (max), or `5,` (min).

[image]

Comment: It really worked but I can't make the names appear on the same row as the result.

Comment: You want names without *Total*? You can just do Find: ` Total` Replace with: ``

Comment: No, no. I mean, when I do the first step, it sum all the 1 values, but the names didn't appear when I group the rows for each pokemon. I will find out how to do it, but the subtotal worked doing what you said. Also, when I selected the column C on the formula didn't appear the SUBTOTAL formula... I'm still thinking what to do (following your instructions in some way) but your answer was helpful! Thanks!